# Bootstrap 4 alpha, dropdowns in nav not working

Tags: navbar, dropdown, bootstrap-4

I'm tinkering with a nav in bootstrap 4, building instead of templating, and for some reason my dropdowns just aren't working. I click them and they take me to the whatever site I've got plugged in, instead of showing me options to choose.  For that matter, my toggler for the hamburger isn't working either. Any ideas?

```
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse" style="background-color: #0E0B16;">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html">EX</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="bio.html">Bio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownPortfolio" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Portfolio
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownPortfolio">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="filmportfolio.html">Film</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="stageportfolio.html">Stage</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="beautyportfolio.html">Beauty</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-sub pull-right">
                <li class = "navbar-text"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> 555-555-5555</li>
                <li class= "navbar-text"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> ex@example.com</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://www.codeply.com/go/7baYqFl5Y9

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the full page code, this is only an educated guess, but, it sounds like you left out jquery and/or bootstrap.js/bootstrap.min.js. The hamburger show/collapse and dropdowns depend on that .js file.